# Ps4 Sharing digital games

Tags: ps4

Ok So me and my brother both share a ps4 and we both have our separate accounts, mine though is set up as the main account which means that he can play any game i buy on the psn store but the question is can i play the games he buys? usually the games he has have a lock on them so i cant play them so i was wondering if someone could tell me why and if there is a possible way that i can play them too. it would help me out alot thank you.

Comment: I believe he just needs to set this PS4 as his primary PS4

Comment: You would have to use his profile, to play his games, he purchased

Answer (score 0):

If your brother the console as his primary one, it will give you access to his digital purchase. More than one account can set the same console as primary.